# ajax php image are follow by alphabetical order

Tags: php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$folder = $_POST['folder'];
$dir = $folder."/";
//start directory 
$dirHandle = opendir($dir); 
$i = 0;
$directoryfiles = array();

while ($file = readdir($dirHandle)) {
    //check only image type file.
    if(!is_dir($file) && preg_match("/.png|.jpg|.gif/i", $file)){
        $i++;
        $totalfiles = "$dir$files";
        $src = $totalfiles;
        $temp = new stdClass;
        $temp->num = $i;
        $temp->src = $src;
        $temp->name = $files;
        $directoryfiles["img".$i] = $temp;
    }
}

// close directory
closedir($dirHandle);

//turn array to json
echo json_encode($directoryfiles);
```

i am using ajax to get image return from php , The problem that I am having is that the image are not being follow by alphabetical order as the docs.

i was trying to use sort($directoryfiles), but is not working.

how do i make sure my image are follow by alphabetical order as the docs ? do scandir() help me ? need help here. thank

the return of conlog

```
image3-000000-023.png
image2-000000-022.png
image1-000000-021.png
image4-000000-024.png
```

the order i need

```
image1-000000-021.png
image2-000000-022.png
image3-000000-023.png
image4-000000-024.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) for your solution.

> asort - Sort an array and maintain index association

See example:

```
$directoryfiles = array("image3-000000-023.png", "image2-000000-022.png", "image1-000000-021.png", "image4-000000-024.png");

//Sort array using asort() function...Place below single line after while loop into your code
asort($directoryfiles);

//Print output...
print('<pre>');
print_r($directoryfiles);
print('</pre>');

//Output...
Array
(
    [2] => image1-000000-021.png
    [1] => image2-000000-022.png
    [0] => image3-000000-023.png
    [3] => image4-000000-024.png
)
```

You can see the output from `asort()` is like what you want.

For live example you can check [PHPFIDDLE](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u40f-3xzd). Click on **Run - F9** and see output.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
<?php
$array1 = array("image3-000000-023.png", "image2-000000-022.png", "image1-000000-021.png", "image4-000000-024.png");
echo "<pre>";
natsort($array1);
echo "\nNatural order sorting\n";
print_r($array1);
?>
```